# Convert 2 dimensional array to string with choice of delimiters

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

How do I convert this array so the output of the code below will be as follows.

```
String[][] array = { { "a", "b" }, { "c" } };

String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String[] row : array) {
    sb.append(Arrays.toString(row))
      .append(lineSeparator);
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

I need the output to look like this

```
a,b,c
```

I am getting this right now

```
[a, b]
[c]
```

Comment: look at StringUtils#join(Object[], char): https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join-java.lang.Object:A-char-

Comment: Why not use an inner loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).flatMap(ar -> Arrays.stream(ar)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

This has been done using Java 8 streams, I don't advice doing this in one line like I did, it's always best to save it into a variable and then printing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringJoiner` instead. IdeoneLink: https://ideone.com/EfodvF

```java
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String[][] array = { { "a", "b" }, { "c" } };
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");

        for (String[] row : array) {
            for(String str: row){
                sj.add(str);
            }
        }


        String result = sj.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
String[][] array = {{"a", "b"}, {"c"}};

String s = "";
for (String[] ar : array) {
    for (String c : ar) {
        s += c + ",";
    }
}
if (s.length() > 1)
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);

System.out.println(s);
```

I believe you're a beginner. Perhaps do some research before posting a question.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html